# Select distinct date part in FOR XML query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to build up some XML from a SQL Server database table.

I need to spit out this XML structure:

```
<shifts>
    <day workDate='2014-11-11'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-11 10:19' enddate='2014-11-11 13:00'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-11 14:00' enddate='2014-11-11 16:00'>
    </day>
    <day workDate='2014-11-12'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-12 10:19' enddate='2014-11-12 13:00'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-12 14:00' enddate='2014-11-12 16:00'>
    </day>
</shifts>
```

my problem is that my XML data is duplicated.  It seems to be because there are 2 records for each date, I end up with:

```
<shifts>
    <day workDate='2014-11-11'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-11 10:19' enddate='2014-11-11 13:00'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-11 14:00' enddate='2014-11-11 16:00'>
    </day>
    <day workDate='2014-11-11'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-11 10:19' enddate='2014-11-11 13:00'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-11 14:00' enddate='2014-11-11 16:00'>
    </day>
    <day workDate='2014-11-12'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-12 10:19' enddate='2014-11-12 13:00'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-12 14:00' enddate='2014-11-12 16:00'>
    </day>
    <day workDate='2014-11-12'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-12 10:19' enddate='2014-11-12 13:00'>
      <shift startdate='2014-11-12 14:00' enddate='2014-11-12 16:00'>
    </day>
</shifts>
```

It would be really great if I could just throw in a "SELECT DISTINCT", but SQL server complains about that because it can't be compared.

```
The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
```

Here is part of the SQL statement..  I've tried to cut most of it out for brevity, but it "should" make sense as it is.

```
SELECT dbo.udf_DATEVALUE(err2.ShiftStartDT) [@workDate]
,
(
    SELECT err3.Shift [@Shift],
         err3.Campus [@Campus],
         CASE WHEN murs3.AssistantNum = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [@isSIC], 
         err3.ShiftStartDT [@startdate],
         err3.ShiftFinishDT [@enddate]
    FROM ExamRoomRoster err3
        INNER JOIN MU_Roster_Supervisor murs3 ON murs3.ExamRoomRosterID = err3.ExamRoomRosterID
        INNER JOIN ExamSupervisor es3 ON es3.ExamSupervisorID = murs3.ExamSupervisorID
    WHERE err3.ExamSessionID = 104
        AND es3.ExamSupervisorID = 1297
        AND dbo.udf_DATEVALUE(err3.ShiftStartDT) = dbo.udf_DATEVALUE(err2.ShiftStartDT)
    ORDER BY err3.Shift
    FOR XML PATH ('Shift'), type
)
FROM ExamRoomRoster err2
ORDER BY dbo.udf_DATEVALUE(err2.ShiftStartDT)
FOR XML PATH ('Day'), type
```

Essentially, there are multiple rose in the ExamRoomRoster table, 1 for each shift, with the start date/time and end date/time values.

I'd really like to just stick in a DISTINCT, then I reakon it would be fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.udf_DATEVALUE(err2.ShiftStartDT) [@workDate]
...
FOR XML PATH ('Day'), type
```

Is there some other way to do this without a DISTINCT??

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the DISTINCT if it works?

Comment: @JamesBlond that's the problem, it doesn't work.  Otherwise I would.  If you add in a DISTINCT, SS spits back "The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable".

Comment: Can't you use a `DISTINCT` in a subquery and afterwards do the `FOR XML` thing with its results?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using CTE or sub query

```
WITH CTE 
AS
( -- your current query
)
SELECT distinct col1, col2 ... 
FROM
CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Keep the result inside subquery and use distinct in outer query. Remove the order by inside the subquery and keep it in outer query

```
select Distinct * from (
SELECT  dbo.udf_DATEVALUE(err2.ShiftStartDT) [@workDate]
...
FOR XML PATH ('Day'), type) A
ORDER BY A.[@workDate]
```